# Появление на кластере Cassandra dropped read message и dropped mutation message

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra

У нас есть кластер/кольцо Cassandra, состоящее из 6 улов(rhel 7.8).
На двух узлах нашей СУБД возникают dropped read message и dropped mutation message

Проверку выполняем с помощью tpstats.

Пробовали сменять механизм GC на g1 с mark sweep compact
Увеличивали таймауты

**Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой и как ее вылечить?**

Answer (score 0):

Обычно такое происходит в нескольких случаях, но тут надо смотреть более детально с логами и т.п.:

- Модель данных не очень правильная - соответственно имеется перекос, и некоторые ноды получают гораздо больше трафика чем другие
- Выполняются запросы с QUORUM/LOCAL_QUORUM, что приводит к ожиданию ответа от других нод
- для drop mutations - может быть блокировка на flush, из-за того что слишком мало flush writers
- на чтение может влиять даже read ahead size в Линуксе

я бы посоветовал сделать следующее:

- настроить постоянный мониторинг, чтобы видеть изменение поведения во времени (рекомендуемые метрики [можно найти вот тут](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/metricsandalerts.html)) - например можно взять вот эту [тулзу](http://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra)
- пройтись по [вот этой документации](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/bestPractices.html) - проверить системные настройки, модель данных и т.п.  Эта документация, выжимка из кучи отчетов которые были написаны архитекторами из DataStax для клиентов
- [собрать диагностику со всех нод кластера](https://github.com/DataStax-Toolkit/diagnostic-collection), и проанализировать логи и т.п., например, с помощью [sperf](https://github.com/DataStax-Toolkit/sperf) (разработан поддержкой DataStax)

Comment: Спасибо!

У нас начали расти drop message даже на кластере без нагрузки...
Вы сталкивались с таким? Как быть?

Comment: тяжело сказать - надо смотреть на логи, метрики и т.п. Может быть система в свопе, может быть постоянно проигрываются хинты и т.д.